# Excel VLookup Unique Nth Value based on criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet structured as such (there is other financial data associated with this but I will only show the relevant data that I am working with for this problem)

```
A   B   
ID  Year
1   2018
1   2018
1   2019
2   2018
3   2019
4   2018
4   2019
5   2018
4   2018
4   2019
6   2018
7   2019
```

In another spreadsheet, I am trying to pull each ID's first 2 unique years. Ex: ID 1 has 3 records, 2018 twice and 2019, So I want to pull 2018, and 2019 for ID 1. The end result should look like this with the formula being placed in the year 1 and year 2 columns.

```
A           B       C
ID          Year 1  Year 2
1           2018    2019
2           2018
3           2019
4           2018    2019
5           2018
6           2018
7           2019
```

I am getting stuck in making the year values unique. I almost had a solution using the SMALL and LARGE functions:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$14 = A2,$B$2:$B$14),1)
```

I end up pulling the year 2018 twice because it appears multiple times. This also is not viable if there are 3 years, since I would need the first 2. How can I change it to make it distinct so that I can look up the 1st and 2nd values accordingly?

Comment: I don't understand why your the end result should have 2018 twice for ID=4.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy over one column and down the range:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13/((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$13=$A2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13<>A2)),1),"")
```

[image]

---

If you want to keep the array form of SMALL(IF()) then use this as an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$13=$A2)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13<>A2),Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1),"")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-shift-Enter.

---

If you have Office 365 Excel it can be done with MINIFS():

```
=MINIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,"<>"&A2)
```

Comment: Sorry about the other quesion, never saw this. Thanks! This works great!

Comment: If this works, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: One issue - When I copy the formula over to the 'year 2' column, for ID 1 it counts the 2018 twice. I see in your image you have it as 2019 in Cell C2, i get 2018 as a result.

Comment: are you dragging the formula over or are you pasting the original formula in C2?  You must put the formula in B2, then drag over one and down the length.  The formula in C2 will change automatically to reference the correct cells.

Comment: Yes I dragged it over. It is not moving to the next unique value for me, just the 2nd instance of 2018.

Comment: What is the actual formula after you drag it over?